# How to replace magnificPopup (ajax) content with new ajax content

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

Im working on a website which has a popup for a product information. Inside the popup is a link which opens a second popup for the shipping information.

What we want is to replace the popup content when the second link is clicked.

Is this possible?

This is what I have been trying so far (no luck)..

```
// first popup
$('.pop-ajax').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        closeBtnInside: true, // put close button on inside

        callbacks: {
            parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
                mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('.l-main');
            },
            ajaxContentAdded: function() {
                // console.log('it works');
            }
        }
});

// Second popup (loads first popup when a link inside is clicked)
$('.pop-product').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    closeBtnInside: true, // put close button on inside

    callbacks: {
        parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
            mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#product-ajax');
        },
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
            console.log('First popup');
            // var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance;
            //     mfpContentContainer = mfp.contentContainer;
            //     mfpContent = mfp.content;


            $('.pop-ajax').click(function(){
                $('.pop-product').magnificPopup('close');
                $('.pop-ajax').magnificPopup({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    closeBtnInside: true, // put close button on inside

                    callbacks: {
                        parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
                            mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('.l-main');
                        },
                        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
                            // console.log('it works');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The second popup is a large content area on the site. One of the links inside this area has a link with the `.pop-ajax` class. However we can't seem to update or replace the popup content with the new content.

Can anyone help shed light on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create nested popups then according to this below link, it is not allowed.
[Issues for Simultaneous Popups](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/36)

But if you want to open just one popup,in which after the click on the inner link just replace the content of the pop up. Then refer to the following link.
[Nested Popups](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbMwqr)

```
$('.first-popup-link, .second-popup-link').magnificPopup({  closeBtnInside:true});
```

In the above code you can find that for two different links same magnificPopup instance was created.